# sending array data with multipart/form-data post request in Axios vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm sending a post request from vue.js project using Axios and it contains a file upload, which requires me to use FormData, I found a nice answer that helped me with FormData:

```
const getFormData = object => Object.keys(object).reduce((formData, key) => {
     formData.append(key, object[key]);
     return formData;
}, new FormData());
```

and for the headers: `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}`.

The POST call looks like this:

```
axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/document/",
      getFormData(this.documentData),
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log("Successfully uploaded: ", response.data)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("error occured: ", err)
      })
```

This is the data I'm sending:

```
documentData: {
      name: '',
      file: '',
      version: '',
      company: '',
      author: '',
      category: []
    }
```

When sending the data with single category id, it works fine, but when I send multiple category ids the following error shows:

```
"category": [
    "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."
]
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What format does the server-side process expect for the `category`? Is it expecting a JSON array or multiple `category` entries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your server-side process is expecting multiple, repeated field names for array types, you'll want something like this

```js
const getFormData = object => Object.entries(object).reduce((fd, [ key, val ]) => {
  if (Array.isArray(val)) {
    val.forEach(v => fd.append(key, v))
  } else {
    fd.append(key, val)
  }
  return fd
}, new FormData());
```

Some server-side processes (PHP for example) require that collection-type fields include a `[]` suffix. If that's what you're working with, change this line

```js
val.forEach(v => fd.append(`${key}[]`, v))
```

---

Also, when sending `FormData` from your browser, **do not** manually set the `Content-type` header. Your browser will do this for you, [including the required boundary tokens](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html)

```js
axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/document/", getFormData(this.documentData))
  .then(response => {
    console.log("Successfully uploaded: ", response.data)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error("error occurred: ", err)
  })
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **json stringfy** ,
I am using it also with vue app

```
formData.append("TeamMembers", JSON.stringify(this.TeamMembers));
```

```
 axios
 .post("/api/pro", formData, {
  onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => console.log(progressEvent.loaded),
  headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data", },  })
```

Team members is an array .. and you can parse it in the other side this way

```js
const myArr = ['bacon', 'lettuce', 'tomatoes'];

const myArrStr = JSON.stringify(myArr);

console.log(myArrStr);
// "["shark","fish","dolphin"]"

console.log(JSON.parse(myArrStr));
// ["shark","fish","dolphin"]
```

Answer (score -3):

Object array passes values

```js
    
var arr=['上海','北京'];
var formData = new FormData();
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 formData.append('city[]',arr[i]);
}
```